# combining two lists into a new list and sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting, merge

```
shares_1 = [50, 100, 75, 200]
shares_2 = [100, 100, 300, 500]
shares_1.extend(shares_2)
print shares_1
```

output [50, 100, 75, 200, 100, 100, 300, 500]

What I want is to assign a variable to the merged list and sort the list.  See my incorrect attempt below  Any suggestions?

```
shares_3.sort() = shares_1.extend(shares_2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Josh Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543590/combining-two-lists-into-a-new-list-and-sorting/6543598#6543598)' answer offers two good methods. There are some general principles to understand here, though: First, generally, when you call a method that alters a list, it will not also *return* the altered list. So...

```
>>> shares_1 = [50, 100, 75, 200]
>>> shares_2 = [100, 100, 300, 500]
>>> print shares_1.extend(shares_2)
None
>>> print shares_1.sort()
None
```

As you can see, these methods don't return anything -- they just alter the list to which they are bound. On the other hand, you could use `sorted`, which *does not* alter the list, but rather copies it, sorts the copy, and returns the copy:

```
>>> shares_1.extend(shares_2)
>>> shares_3 = sorted(shares_1)
>>> shares_3
[50, 75, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 300, 300, 500, 500]
```

Second, be aware that you can *never* assign to a function call.

```
>>> def foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> foo() = 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 9):

```
shares_3 = sorted(shares_1 + shares_2)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
shares_3 = shares_1 + shares_2
shares_3.sort()
```

Alternatively,

```
shares_1.extend(shares_2)
shares_1.sort()
```